# Find IP Address and Port of Internet Radio Channel (TuneIn)

Tags: html, streaming, webradio, tunein

I am trying to find the IP address and port number of radio station on TuneIn: http://tunein.com/radio/...../

I've looked through the source and I can't seem to find it.
I have also tried to research a solution to this question but I couldn't find anything useful

Answer (score 0):

TuneIn is a simple white pages service, it does not offer a streaming service. If you hear web radio with poor audio quality with TuneIn, it is the web radio's fault, not TuneIn.

Open your web radio with TuneIn.

Right-Click on web page end select "Inspect (Q)" (I try with Firefox)

Make sure the URL column is shown, if not, enable the display of the URL column.
Right click on the row of column names, the list of columns appears, check URL.

Click Play on TuneIn

Type mp3 in the textbox "filter"

Scroll, you can view original URL, port e mountpoint of the
from original web radio.

remember: TuneIn is a simple white pages service, it does not offer a streaming service. If you hear web radio with poor audio quality with TuneIn, it is the web radio's fault, not TuneIn.